# How does a virtual password keyboard with 2 numbers per button work?

Tags: javascript, html, input, password-protection

I'm looking for a way to replicate the following picture password input. I tried many ways but could not find the name of this type of input which is used in many banks in Brazil.

The password is composed of numbers only and as you can see you will click the buttons that have your password but people next to you can't determine the exact password because every button has 2 numbers.

[image: Example from a site]

For example, the password 12345 would require pressing buttons: second, first, fifth, first and fourth.
Password 424242 would required pressing the first button 6 times.

The keyboard is randomized at every page reload.

This unfolds into 2 questions:
How are the numbers encoded in the client side so that in the server side I know what buttons were pressed.

Thinking about the backend, how do you store such passwords **securely** so that you still be able to find the user with the mixed inputted password.

The site part must be HTML/Javascript for the input and the backend can be any database in PHP/NodeJS/Python. I'm more concerned about the method description than the implementation, so pseudo-code is fine too.